# How to get my wp8 device's resolution?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I used the examples below to retrieve a device's resolution, but it doesn't seem to be returning correct data. For example, my device is a Lumia 920, which has a resolution of 1280x768, but the code below returns 800x480. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or know of an alternative method for retrieving the correct resolution?

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight
```

Comment: Is your application compiled for WP8? A WP7 application will always return 480*800 for backward compatibility reasons, even when executed on a WP8 device.

Comment: but, my application was compiled on WP8 development environment, and no any relationship with WP7, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ScaleFactor property to retrieve screen resolution. [This article](http://mobileosgeek.com/how-to-retrieve-the-screen-resolution-of-windows-phone-8-using-c/) helps you.
 Also see [this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/f4aab4fb-867c-4ccc-805e-3296caabd6b2).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you for resolutions size for WP8 Devices

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx